# Git Hub Pull request builder plugin

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins, pull-request

I am new to git. I am currently performing a poc using githubpullrequestbuilder plugin.

The GIT configuration looks as follows:

[image]

The plugin configuration is as below:
[image]

I wish to achieve the below use cases:

1. Whenever a new Pull request is created a jenkins job should be triggered.**(i was able to get this working)**
2. The job should be triggered incase the PR is updated with new additional commits. E.g: Before a PR is merged, in case there are any new checkins done which are a now a part of the existing PR, this should trigger a jenkins build.**(I am not able to get this working.)**
3. The job should also be triggered if a simple push onto the master branch is made.**(I am not able to get this working)**

**

> What is the correct configuration to achieve the above?

**

Note: I have a git web hook which is set to pull request and push events. Below is a screenshot.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> The job should be triggered incase the PR is updated with new additional commits. E.g: Before a PR is merged, in case there are any new checkins done which are a now a part of the existing PR, this should trigger a jenkins build.(I am not able to get this working.)

I'm not sure what you fully want here, do you want to combine both PR to a single PR when a check in is done immediately while a PR is being done ?? I don't think that's possible, why not wait till all check-in's are done and then do a pull request (Pull request are generally done when everything is finalized and you are sure of what needs to go(pushed) in general done in PROD environment)

There is an Trigger Setup option with cancel Build on update. But then you will have to trigger a new PR, you can check other option under Trigger Setup on commit related query

[image]

Unless you provide more details on what you require I cant help any further :)

> The job should also be triggered if a simple push onto the master branch is made.(I am not able to get this working)

I don't think Git Pull Requests Handles Push. For that you will have to explicitly check the GitHub Branches in the Build Trigger option, and you can add restriction on the branches like 'build only Master'.

P.S. As for your webhook you have given permission to push and pull from Git but the same needs to be applied from Jenkins side :)

Comment: I do understand that PR should be raised post all the checkins are done, however in case there are any new check-ins done to the same branch, the PR will get the updated and i need to job to be triggered.

Comment: So that job will be queued. But the issue with that is that, commits made in the first PR will be overridden with the new PR changes.Also GitHub will not allow you to do a pull request, if a pull request is made on the same file, so essentially the developer of the 2nd PR will have to update his code and re-initiate a PR

Comment: If you really want to deploy multiple PR then give this a shot(Involves Pipelines) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650629/how-to-run-continuous-integration-in-parallel-across-multiple-pull-requests